# Snake game movement issue Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to create a basic snake game using Swift and Spritekit. I have a sprite moving on the screen and when i swipe it starts moving in the swipe direction. I do this in the update method where I change the position of the sprite based on the swipe direction, a set speed and a fixed duration.

e.g. direction.x * blockMovePerSecond * CGFloat(actionDuration)

I have the sprites following each other, however, as soon as i swipe and the first sprite changes direction, the one following it moves diagonally instead of first on the x-axis and then the y-axis like a normal snakes game.

I tried the following options:

- Tried keeping the distance that the sprite moves on each update equal
  to the distance between the two sprites. However, the sprite runs off
  the screen when i do that.
- Made the first sprite create a path for the rest of the sprites to follow. However, the second sprite
  runs off the screen and never shows up again. I think the problem is
  because the path is open.

Here's my move method code for the sprites following the first sprite (snake head):

```
{
   var temp:NSValue = lastNodeLocation // the lastnodelocation is from first sprite location
   var tempNodeDirection = lastNodeDirection
   let actionDuration = 1.0

   let distanceToMoveThisFrame = tempNodeDirection.CGPointValue() * blockMovePerSecond * CGFloat(actionDuration)
   var currentPosition = NSValue(CGPoint: blocksOfAlphabets[i].position)
   let beforeDistance = CGPoint(x: temp.CGPointValue().x - currentPosition.CGPointValue().x, y: temp.CGPointValue().y - currentPosition.CGPointValue().y)


   lastNodeLocation = NSValue(CGPoint: blocksOfAlphabets[i].position)
   // move node to new location
   var moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(temp.CGPointValue(), duration: 1.0)
   node.runAction(moveAction)
}
```

Can somebody please help?

Thanks
Shuchi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your problem is that the runAction-methods don't wait to complete. So if you call another runAction-method while a sprite is already running an action, the new action will be started immediately.

You can work with sequences to finish the x-axis first: [SKAction:sequence](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013017-CH1-SW12)

Comment: True.. That makes sense. Let me try that out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing to do here is to keep an array of snake sprite components (let's call these sprites a "Rib").

Every 5 seconds add a new Rib to the end of the array to make the snake grow.

Then, each half second in the update() method (or however long you want it to be):

- check for any swipes that have happened since the last update and change direction of the first rib (the snake head) in the direction of the swipe.
- now run through the snake array in reverse and set the location of node (n) to the node position of node (n-1).

There are other ways you could do it but I think this would be the easiest.